# What are some best practices for supporting profiling in a php application?

Tags: php, performance, profiling

I am starting a new project for a high performance php web application. I would like to continually profile the application as I add features to it that way I am able to quickly spot bottlenecks during the development process. I have have xdebug configured on my software stack and I am comfortable with using it but I was hoping to get some insight into best practices when developing an application from the ground up. I would like to bake functionality for gathering metrics from the very start. What are some suggestions to this end?

If it makes a difference, the application will be heavily object oriented and will make use of Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most performance bottlenecks will probably come from the db.  Query profiling should be crucial.  Its something relatively easy to profile and speeding up slow queries can have HUGE performance bumps.  This can be just as easily accomplished through `EXPLAIN` and slow query log but it is nice to be able to view these metrics on page load.

Zend has support for this out of the box
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Zend_Db_Profiler. Also I discovered ZFDebug which is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. It can be found on github https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug